# PHP Laravel - Eloquent is returning boolean fields randomly sometimes as 0 1 and others as true false when calling the method json

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel Eloquent to write a REST API. When calling `json` from `response()` to return the object, boolean fields are returned as 0/1 sometimes and as false/true others. I would like to unify the format and make it all as 0,1 or as false,true instead of it being random

here is the code sample:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $obj = MyObject::findOrFail($id);
    return response()->json($obj,200);
}
```

this return 0,1

and this code when the object is created return true, false not only for the status but for the boolean values in the `$obj`

```
return response()->json([
        'status' => (bool) $obj,
        'data'   => $obj,
        'message' => $obj ? 'new obj created!' : 'an error has occurred'
    ], 201);
```

So, how to make them all 0 and 1 or all true or false?

Comment: Well why do you want to ? since in php 0 = false and 1 = true, and on your code you are only checking if it is true or false as well.

Comment: @pinoyCoder because i am writing a REST API for and ANDROID app that uses java.. consistency is very important since i need to make an equivalent class for Object and need to specify the type of the boolean field.. and &quot;true&quot; is NOT the same as 1 according to Gson

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try casts property for all boolien fields in model.

```
protected $casts = [
    'is_published' => 'boolean',
];
```

Comment: i added this for my clolumn name to my model then this is worked as well for me thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use Laravel Accessor [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function getIsPublishedAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value == 1 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

It will always return based on your `$value`.

Comment: but i dont want to always return true, and my problem is not with status its with boolean fields inside $obj.. like i have is_published fields.. in the first code it's returned as 0 and 1 yet when i create the obj its returned as truw, false